# unable to get an array of svg files from public folder to component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

here i am having some 20  svg file's in the images folder

```
public 
  |-images
        -| 20 svg files
```

how ever i am able to retrieve only 1 image that to if set the images src folder

```
 import React from 'react';

import svg from "../src/images/image1.svg"
class App extends React.Component{

   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <img src={svg} alt="info"></img>
       </div>
     )
   }
}

export default App;
```

so here how can i retrieve an array of images from public folder can use in component

update :

say my folder structure is like

```
public
      |- images
           |-50 images
   src
    |- component1
    |- component 2
           |- component2.js 


  if i am calling in component2.js


   importAll(r) {
        return r.keys().map(r);
      }
      componentWillMount() {
        images = this.importAll(require.context('/public/same-size/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            {images.map((image, index) => <img key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img>)}
          </div>
        )
      }
```

then i am getting error module not found

Comment: Why do you want to avoid setting the src attribute?

Comment: Usually in react we have to large images set in public folder right and in src also how can we get an array of images directly I'm not able to import folder

Comment: What is you end goal here? Showing all the images in that public folder?

Comment: Like I told u retieve all the images like an array and using map I want show It in table row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can go about it this way:

```
import React from 'react';

var images = [];

class App extends React.Component{
   function importAll(r) {
     return r.keys().map(r);
   }
   componentWillMount() {
     images = this.importAll(require.context('./../../images/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
   }
   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         {images.map((image, index) => <img key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img>)}
       </div>
     )
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This will import all the images from src or public folder?

Comment: Yes. Just replace "./" with your appropriate directory path inside `require.context()`

Comment: Do I need to install any packages npm require-context ?

Comment: Technically, you need Webpack but chances are you are already using it with react

Comment: it worked @faisal it will work in in production also right ?

Comment: on button click how can we render it is not working on button click though

Comment: Yes, it would work in production. Please explain a bit more about the requirements of button click. If this is unrelated to this question, I'd suggest you create a simple question for that.

Comment: just now i tried your approach  using public folder but it didnt work in the nested folder structure please check the updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193809/discussion-between-faisal-rahman-avash-and-dexter).